# Using ggmap. What the error "Computation failed in `stat_density2d()`: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed" means?

Tags: r, gis, heatmap, ggmap

I am using R as a GIS tool for creating maps.
I wanted to create a contour, or heatmap of a species distribution on a geographical area.
I wanted to see on the map where each species (animal or plant) is present and color the area in a specific color. 
I am using a dataset downloaded from GBIF.

You can download the datasets from my GitHub ([https://github.com/RosarioIacono/stackoverflow_question/blob/master/species2t.csv][1]).

```
species <- read.delim("./species.txt")
```

```
library(readr)
species2t <- read_csv("species2t.csv")
View(species2t)


ggmap(map1)+
    stat_density_2d(data = subset(species2t, order=="Anseriformes"),
aes( x = decimalLongitude,
     y = decimalLatitude,
     fill = ..level..),
                    alpha = .3,
                    geom = "polygon",
                    color = species)+
theme(legend.position = "none")
```

But I get an error:

```
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (190): colour
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have your data frame, but I think your problem comes with one of the groups having n=1. This can be caused by, some of your species_dens's longitude and latitude being out of the map:

```
library("ggmap")
map <- c(left = -0.7, bottom = 53, right =-0.3 , top =53.6 )

map1<-get_stamenmap(map, maptype = "toner-lite")

#simulate data
species_dens = data.frame(species=c("A","B","A","B"),
decimalLongitude=c(-0.4,-0.5,-0.3,-0.2),
decimalLatitude=c(53.1,53.2,53.3,53.4))

# returns your error
ggmap(map1)+
geom_density_2d(data = species_dens,aes( x = decimalLongitude,
                                             y = decimalLatitude,
                                             colour = species))
```

From the above, you can see the last data point is off the map, so if you do geom_density with your limits, the species "B" will have n=1. Using your current dataset, if you set the colors to be species, you still end up with n=1:

```
library(readr)
species2t <- read_csv("species2t.csv")

X=subset(species2t, order=="Anseriformes")
table(X$species)

       Anas crecca Anas platyrhynchos      Anas strepera        Anser anser 
                 1                  1                  1                  1 
   Aythya fuligula        Cygnus olor    Tadorna tadorna 
                 1                  1                  1
```

This means you cannot colour according to species. But you see how this order is distributed:

```
ggmap(map1)+
stat_density_2d(data = X,
aes( x = decimalLongitude,
     y = decimalLatitude,
     fill = ..level..),
     alpha = .3,
     geom = "polygon")+
theme(legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I tried and even by expanding the limits over the maximum latitude and longitude does not do it. I included a link to the data in my question if this may help.

Comment: Ok your problem is this. You are giving a frequency table, and doing a density on it. So every species has data point n=1, and this doesn't make sense at all.. You need to plot using the original dataset

Comment: Arh ok.. You have exactly overlapping long and lat.. what is the plot you are expecting?

Comment: I think you spotted the problem, in downloading the data I did not get the data from an area I selected, but from a single point and of course that cannot be plotted. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yeah no problem, so the take home is, you cannot do geom_density() on n=1, just make sure of that before you plot

Comment: Thank you very much. I replaced the dataset with a working one, but not still able to have different polygons according to the levels of the factor.

Comment: Hey @Rosario, so you have the working dataset in the same github link? Maybe update your question with the code you are trying now? Thanks!

Comment: thank, it is my first question on here, I did not know where I could post it.

Comment: It should be up now

Comment: You have the same problem, when you do subset(species2t, class=="Arachnida" & year > "1995"& year <"2000"), this is blank

Comment: Hey @Rosario, you really have to check your input data before you plot..

Comment: Hey @StupidWolf even if I change the subset, I still get the same type of error.

Comment: Ok @Rosario, I can answer your current question, but I need to say that SO is not meant for this. I understand that one issue usually leads to the next, and that's part of programming, to break down your problems.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to this, what should I have done? Do I need to repost the question in a new thread?

Comment: No worries. Yeah let's say for example, your current question says: "Using ggmap. What the error “Computation failed in `stat_density2d()`: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed” means?" I answered this saying it comes from n=1

Comment: So if you have a new problem, or you are not sure how to format the data to plot what you would like to visualize, do post it as another question. I am sure everyone can appreciate a good question.

Comment: This makes totally sense. I will post this as a new question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can see my answer above, that will explain why you still get an error.